# Delete rows unless they contain Value > 100

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with columns of data. I'm trying to delete any rows where all of the values in that row are less than 100.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub deleterows()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lRow = 900
    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(iCntr, 1) < 100 Then
            Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this only looks in the first column and will delete rows where values greater than 100 exist in other columns. Can someone help me to get it looking at all columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to look at the maximum in a given row, editing your code like so, see my comments for details.

```
Sub deleterows()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lRow = 900
    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        ' Check if the maximum value in the columns A:F is less than 100
        ' If it is, then all of the values are!
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & iCntr & ":F" & iCntr)) < 100 Then
            Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Of course you can change the "F" to any letter(s) you wish.